# Char * function in C

Tags: c

I am currently trying to use a random string generator to produce a string. It looks like this:

```
char *randstring(int length) {

    static char charset[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789,.-#'?!";        
    char *randomString = NULL;
    int n = 0;
    if (length) {
        randomString = malloc(sizeof(char) * (length +1));

        if (randomString) {            
            for (n = 0;n < length;n++) {            
                int key = rand() % (int)(sizeof(charset) -1);
                randomString[n] = charset[key];
            }

            randomString[length] = '\0';
        }
    }
    return randomString;
}
```

I am trying to call it like this:

```
srand(time(NULL));
int r = rand()%1000;
char *string[1000];
&string = randomstring(r);
```

But when I do this, I get the following error:

```
error: invalid lvalue in assignment.
```

I have looked online but I can not figure out why this is not working. Any suggestions? It has to do with the pointer, I assume.

Comment: the invalid lvalue is &string.  you cant change the location of the pointer to string.  Just remove &

Comment: `char *string[1000];&string = randomstring(r);` --> `char *string = randomstring(r);`

Comment: You've declared an array of 1000 char pointers, and then you try to assign a char pointer to the address of that array. The compiler is trying to tell you that doesn't make any sense ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most likely, the correct code is:

```
char *string = randomstring(52);
```

If for some reason you wanted to keep the array of character pointers, you could also do:

```
char *string[1000];
string[0] = randomstring(102);
```

Comment: When I do the first one, I get an error: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast

Comment: @user081608, did you provide the declaration of `randomstring` before you use it? If not, the compiler assumes `int` as the return type.

Comment: @user081608: It looks good to me: https://gist.github.com/sharth/d2caee7c14bf894329a5

Answer (score 3):

```
&string = randomstring(r);
```

should be

```
string[0] = randomstring(r);
```

Comment: When I do that, I get error: incompatible types in assignment